# PHPSpreadsheet to update an existing file writes only the last record of the query

Tags: loops, while-loop, phpspreadsheet

Hello i am trying to write an existing xlsx file using phpspreadsheet with setActiveSheetIndexByName(sheetname) and setcellvalue with reference and value, but it updates only the last record. spent more than 12 hours on this.

i tried foreach instead of while and used a counter to increment, but none worked.

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
$prospect = $_REQUEST['prospect'];
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

            $sql1 = mysqli_query($db,"select filename,sheetname, row, responsecol,compliancecol,response, compliance from spreadsheet where `prospect`='$prospect' and response <>'' order by row");    
            //$row=1;           
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1))
            {
                $filename= $row1['filename']; //test.xlsx
                $sheetname= $row1['sheetname']; // mysheet
                $responsecol= $row1['responsecol'].$row1['row']; //D1
                $response= $row1['response']; //response
                $compliancecol= $row1['compliancecol'].$row1['row']; //C1
                $compliance= $row1['compliance']; //compliance

                $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($filename);
                $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheetname)
                                ->setCellValue($compliancecol,$compliance)
                                ->setCellValue($responsecol,$response); 
                                //$row++;
            }

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');        
$writer->save("newfile.xlsx");
exit;
?>
```

i wish each of the row from mysqli result updates each reference cell with value.

Answer (score 0):

The easys way is to set a Limit of 1 to your MySQL query. That takes only one value from your data. If you will the last you should sort DESC.

```
$sql1 = mysqli_query($db,"select filename,sheetname, row, responsecol,compliancecol,response, compliance from spreadsheet where `prospect`='$prospect' and response <>'' order by row DESC LIMIT 1");
```